# Why does hyperref refer to the wrong place when I define a new theorem?

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, texshop

I am writing a pdf textbook (using miktex & TexShop). The outline of the tex file is as below. Problem 2 refers to Problem 1. However, hyperref directs the reader to Thm 1. Is there a way for me to fix it? (The problems at the end of the section should be numbered from 1 and the problem section should not advance the section number.)

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{problem}[theorem]{Problem}
\begin{document}

\section{Logic}

\begin{theorem}\label{thm1} Blah \end{theorem}
\eject

\section*{Problems}\setcounter{theorem}{0}

\begin{problem}\label{prob1}
Prove $P \Rightarrow Q$
\end{problem}

\begin{problem}
Prove the inverse implication of Problem \ref{prob1}.
\end{problem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the reason for `\newtheorem{problem}[theorem]{Problem}`? Just do `\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}[section]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the structure is always

```
\section{Title}

Text for the section

\clearpage

\section*{Problems}

Problems
```

then you can just define `problem` as numbered within sections.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}[section]

\begin{document}

\section{Logic}

\begin{theorem}\label{thm1} Blah \end{theorem}

\clearpage

\section*{Problems}

\begin{problem}\label{prob1}
Prove $P \Rightarrow Q$
\end{problem}

\begin{problem}
Prove the inverse implication of Problem \ref{prob1}.
\end{problem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Don't use `\eject`, but `\clearpage`.